# Getting error when deploying Aura Component to an Aura community

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, lightning-community

Getting Error when deploying my Aura (community) component to PROD:

`CommunityPortal | Site.com |  Implement "forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" for the Aura component c:MyAuraComponent with ID 849d2c1d-acca-4b47-89d4-6f2c39645c1d and try again.`

But I have implemented the interface and deployment was fine in lower envs.

```
<aura:component controller="MyAuraComponent"
    implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes"
    access="global">
```

Any tips?

EDIT : As per @fred comment I deployed first the component then the community and no more trouble :)

Comment: How are you doing the deployment? What are you deploying at the same time?

Comment: experience bundle + the aura component (+perm set/profiles/classes/roles/...)

Answer (score 1):

Problem resolved by first deploying the aura component (and its dependencies) and then the community/experience site.

Comment: This is now a Known Issue for this: https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000uXPYMAA4/forcecommunityavailableforallpagetypes-error-while-deploying-experience-bundle